# Tooltips function to each option in a drop down list in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to be able to add a tooltip function to my LibreOffice Calc document.

I have a drop down list done with Data -> Validity. Either with a Cell Range or a List.

How can I, as simple as possible, insert a tooltip text over each option in that drop down list?

I haven't written Macros before (Tools -> Macros), I am not familiar with Visual Basic, Pyhton or Java. 
Any installs, plugins and/or a code snippet I can get help with?

For example:

```
1 (tooltip: this is option one)
2 (tooltip: this is option two)
3 (tooltip: option 3 this is)
```

I have Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: What kind of drop-down list: *Data -> Validity*, or a spreadsheet form (*View -> Toolsbars -> Form Controls*), or a macro dialog (*Tools -> Macros -> Organize Dialogs*)?  In any case, you will probably need to write an event listener.  For LO programming, Basic is most common, Python is my favorite, and Java is another good alternative.

Comment: My first attempt was the Data->Validity. I hoped there was a simple solution. But I guess I'll have to start learning Basic, Python or Java now.

Comment: For Python introductory documentation, see [here](http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html) or [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python) and use [APSO](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python).

Answer (score 2):

One thing that can be done easily is to add comments to each cell with *Insert -> Comment*.

Then, for example, select cell A5 as shown in the image below and go to *Data -> Validity*.  Set the cell range source as A1 to A3.

[image: data validity and tooltips]

Alternatively, an example of a tooltip using label controls is at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=57791.

A solution closer to what you described in the question may be possible by writing an event listener.  [XListBox](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/awt/XListBox.html) has an event called [itemStateChanged](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/awt/XItemListener.html).  Perhaps instead of displaying a tooltip, display the information in a text box when this event occurs.

**EDIT**:

Here is example code that shows my idea.  Use APSO to run `showdlg()`.

```py
import uno
import unohelper
from com.sun.star.awt import XItemListener

Items = [
        ("Item 1", "This is the first item"),
        ("Item 2", "This is the second item"),
        ("Item 3", "This is the third item"),
    ]

def showdlg():
    doc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    dlg = TooltipDialog(doc)
    dlg.show()

class TooltipDialog(XItemListener, unohelper.Base):
    def __init__(self, doc):
        self.parent = doc.CurrentController.Frame.ContainerWindow
        self.dlg = None
        self.label = None

    def show(self):
        toolkit = self.parent.getToolkit()
        ctx = uno.getComponentContext()
        smgr = ctx.ServiceManager
        model = smgr.createInstanceWithContext(
            "com.sun.star.awt.UnoControlDialogModel", ctx)
        dialog = smgr.createInstanceWithContext(
            "com.sun.star.awt.UnoControlDialog", ctx)
        model.setPropertyValue("PositionX", 100)
        model.setPropertyValue("PositionY", 100)
        model.setPropertyValue("Width", 200)
        model.setPropertyValue("Height", 75)
        model.setPropertyValue("Title", "Tooltip Listbox")

        listbox = model.createInstance(
            "com.sun.star.awt.UnoControlListBoxModel")
        listbox.setPropertyValue("PositionX", 20)
        listbox.setPropertyValue("PositionY", 10)
        listbox.setPropertyValue("Width", 40)
        listbox.setPropertyValue("Height", 20)
        listbox.setPropertyValue("Dropdown", True)
        listbox.setPropertyValue("Name", "ListBox1")
        for pos in range(len(Items)):
            listbox.insertItemText(pos, Items[pos][0])
        model.insertByName("ListBox1", listbox)

        label = model.createInstance(
            "com.sun.star.awt.UnoControlFixedTextModel")
        label.setPropertyValue("PositionX", 70)
        label.setPropertyValue("PositionY", 10)
        label.setPropertyValue("Width", 100)
        label.setPropertyValue("Height", 20)
        label.setPropertyValue("Name", "Label1")
        label.setPropertyValue("Label", "(Please select an item.)")
        model.insertByName("Label1", label)

        dialog.setModel(model)
        control = dialog.getControl("ListBox1")
        control.addItemListener(self)
        self.label = dialog.getControl("Label1")
        dialog.createPeer(toolkit, None)
        self.dlg = dialog
        self.dlg.execute()
        self.dlg.dispose()

    def itemStateChanged(self, itemEvent):
        """XItemListener event handler."""
        pos = itemEvent.Source.SelectedItemPos
        description = Items[pos][1]
        self.label.setText(description)
```

[image: tooltip list box]

As you may notice, the example does not contain any special formatting.  It should be straightforward to change it to modify the label to be a yellow 3-D box for example.  Also, the example could be adapted to show a message that goes away after a short time using [threads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).  It still will not be a real tooltip, but it can be made to look and work a lot like one, if that is important to you.

A similar solution could be implemented using a spreadsheet [lookup](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP) function, without any need for macros.  The text would appear in a cell rather than a separate dialog, and the cell value would be calculated based on the data validity result.  That would not allow as much flexibility about how it looks, but it should be able to display the description without a problem.

Comment: I tried the Add comment thing, but the comments didn't get inherited into the actual  drop down list. Thanks for your ideas. I have some learning to do, and I guess I'll be back to this question in the future to verify the answer.

Comment: Correct; that doesn't really do what you asked.  But I mentioned it because it shows tooltips.  Edit the question or post a new one if you need help writing the event listener.  You could also try ask.libreoffice.org, which allows attachments.  In that case, be sure to post a link to this question.

Comment: I've edited the question so I might get help with a little codesnippet.